# Did Matlab 2017a change how it imports external java classes?

Tags: java, matlab, pdfbox

I'm calling PDFBox from Matlab to figure out how many pages there are in a PDF. Everything works great with Matlba 2016b and prior. I can import the library and load a PDF without a problem:

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
pdfFile = PDDocument.load(filename);
```

---

When I run the same thing in 2017a, I get the following error:

```
No method 'load' with matching signature found for class 
'org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument'.
```

I can change the line after the import so that the function signature matches:

```
jFilename = java.lang.String(filename);
pdfFile = PDDocument.load(jFilename.getBytes());
```

However, this causes PDFBox to have problems when I call `load`:

```
Java exception occurred:
java.io.IOException: Error: End-of-File, expected line
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.BaseParser.readLine(BaseParser.java:1111)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parseHeader(COSParser.java:1874)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.COSParser.parsePDFHeader(COSParser.java:1853)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdfparser.PDFParser.parse(PDFParser.java:242)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1093)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1071)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1053)
at org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument.load(PDDocument.java:1038)
```

This error seems to occur regardless of the PDF I'm trying to load. I'm getting the same exception with PDFBox 1.8.10 and 2.0.6.

---

I'm left with 2 questions:

1. Did Matlab 2017a change how it passes strings to Java? I didn't see anything in the [release notes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html) about this.
2. What could be causing the PDFBox error? Matlab is still on Java 1.7 in 2017a so I wouldn't think there should be any difference in how PDFBox works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like the method you are calling is from [PDDocument version 1.8.11](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.11/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.lang.String))

In the latest version, [PDDocument version 2.0.2](https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDDocument.html#load(java.io.File)) the method signature for accepting a file name no longer exists.

Change your code to the following, and it should work.

```
pdfFile = PDDocument.load(java.io.File(filename));
```

Comment: The error with `PDDocument.load(jFilename.getBytes());` is because PDFBox believes you're passing a PDF as byte stream.